# Is it possible to get oAuth to stay within an iFrame and not take up the parent window?

Tags: iframe, oauth, twitter-oauth, linkedin-api, facebook-oauth

On https://www.eventhello.com/overridden_routes/not_mobile, I have an iFrame displaying the mobile version of our application. When from within the iFrame a visitor tries to connect with LinkedIn, Twitter, or Facebook using OAuth, it takes over the parent window.

Is there any way to have the open auth open in a new window and then go back to the iframe within the parent window when complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible nor wanted behavior. The user would be unable to confirm the URL they are accessing. I certainly wouldn't enter my credentials into an iframe.

Comment: That makes sense... I edited the question to find a middle ground that would make the user experience secure and not take the parent window away from the page.

Comment: You could try to close the window when the callback returns, but it probably won't be supported in all browsers. That's more of a Javascript question.

Comment: The main reason not to allow framing of pages wherein you enter passwords or other credentials is clickjacking.